Relationship between Radar Cross Section (RCS) and radar receive dwell samples
I'm trying to understand the relationship between a "bulk" RCS value and range-compressed samples from a radar.
I think it is a straightforward relationship for objects that show up in a single range bin, but it isn't obvious to me for a large shape whose response would show up in many range bins.
For example: A sphere has a known signature following this plot but if I have a 20m radius sphere and a radar with a range resolution of one meter then the sphere will show up in at least 20 range bins. Is there a way to combine all of those samples to recreate the bulk radar cross-section?
Thank you.

Envidia’s answer is solid, and the last point he makes is key. A sphere can be thought of as approaching an isotropic radiator. However, radar scattering is highly anisotropic for typical targets, so statistical distributions are necessary when measuring RCS. But yes, you can sum up all of the returns and rearrange the RRE to estimate the RCS as Envidia showed.

You certainly can, and the semantics on what you mean by "bulking together" change depending on what you're actually trying to do.
For example, in certain situations we may want to be able to do some simple classification of a target so we can hit it with an effector in a particular place. Using techniques to get good range and angle resolutions, you will have independent responses in multiple range and/or angle bins. You can then start to make some inferences about the extent of the target, its attitude in space, etc.
If your goal is to have a measure of the total power returned from multiple points to infer a single RCS value, then you can estimate that by associating all of the returns together, which are from the same target, and add them together.
Recall the basic two-way radar range equation:
$$P_r= \frac{P_tG^2\lambda^2\sigma_0}{(4\pi)^3R^4}$$
When you process a return at a given range bin, you have an estimate for $P_r$ and $R$, so you can estimate an RCS $\sigma_0$ via:
$$\hat{\sigma_0} = \frac{\hat{P_r}(4\pi)^3\hat{R}^4}{P_tG^2\lambda^2}$$
Other system parameters come in to yield a more accurate estimate (like losses over frequencies, DSP losses, etc.), but this will get you in the ballpark. Now since you have multiple detection bins and you want to yield an aggregate RCS, you would simply estimate the RCS for each and add them together. Again, the harder task in this is correctly classifying the multiple returns being from the same target. Also in a real system, you also have noise to contend with, so low RCS returns might not even be detectable to begin with.
Another important aspect to consider is that depending on how fast you are performing detections or if the target is maneuvering, the RCS of the target can fluctuate significantly. This is where you start looking at Swerling models, which statistically describe how RCS changes based on a pulse-to-pulse or an entire dwell timeline, and if the target is made up of multiple scatterers where one is dominant or multiple scatterers were none are dominant.

Thank you @Envidia, I should have added that this is to validate a radar simulation that I'm creating in which I'm able to place a PEC sphere in free space.
